# What is the most efficient way to search for a sub-string

Tags: ruby, string

In the below string I would like to get the revision number which is 153. This part is inside the string which beside the text "Revision: 153\n".

```
string = "Path: blah\blah\nWorking Copy Root Path: blah\blah\nURL: blah\blah\nRelative URL: ^/README.txt\nRepository Root: blah\blah\nRepository UUID: 2d7234b632a-38239d-4384f-9ac3-c05286096652\nRevisio
    n: 153\nNode Kind: file\nSchedule: normal\nLast Changed Author: user_name\nLast Changed Rev: 153\nLast Changed Date: 2014-11-27 11:38:21 +0530 (Thu, 27 Nov 2014)\nText Last Updated: 2014-11-27 12:
    05:24 +0530 (Thu, 27 Nov 2014)\nChecksum: 7ecb9f79f244r4f996e637d6f23\n\n"
```

Currently I am doing it this way :

```
string.split('Revision').last.split('Node').first.chomp.gsub(': ','').to_i
```

Which outputs `153`.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: You can use Regex for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String's `[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and a regular expression here:

```
string[/Revision:\s(\d+)/, 1]
```

Comment: @theTinMan I didn't include any links in my answer. So you should address your comment to "mudasobwa"

Comment: @mudasobwa, when writing anchor text for links, use something that indicates what is being linked to. "can use" tells us nothing about where the link will take us. See "[Don't use 'click here' as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)" and related links at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression.
For example, something like following:

```
string.scan(/Revision: (\d+)/)
```

Clarifying a bit more, if you want to catch multiple occurrences use this.